# combining multiple unicode character

Tags: string, swift, unicode

I wanted to combine multiple unicode code point to print one character using swift language

```
    let str:String = "\u{0C95}\u{0CBE}"
    let combinedCahr:Character = Character(str)
```

This prints `ಕಾ`. 
**My question is:**
I just want combine code dynamically some thing like below. The following code doesn't compile.

```
    let point1 = 0x0C95
    let point2 = 0x0CBE
    let str:String = "\u{(point1)}\u{(point2)}"
    let combinedCahr:Character = Character(str)
```

How to dynamically combine two or more unicode code point to produce on character?

Comment: Shouldn't "\u{(point1)}\u{(point2)}" in hex format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string `"\u{0C95}\u{0CBE}"` is interpreted by the Swift compiler, which unfortunately means you can't build it up using string interpolation which is a runtime operation.  So you need to look for another approach.

`String` has an initializer which takes UTF16 code units:

```
/// Returns an initialized `String` object that contains a
/// given number of characters from a given array of Unicode
/// characters.
public init(utf16CodeUnits: UnsafePointer<unichar>, count: Int)
```

When you see something taking an `UnsafePointer` of a type `T`, you can call that function with `[T]`.  Since the initializer needs the count as well, just build an Swift array of `unichar` and pass that array and its count to the constructor:

```
let point1: unichar = 0x0C95
let point2: unichar = 0x0CBE

let units = [point1, point2]
let str = String(utf16CodeUnits: units, count: units.count)
let combinedChar = Character(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining strings combines (extended) grapheme clusters to a single character,
so this is an alternative solution:

```
let point1 = 0x0C95
let point2 = 0x0CBE

let s1 = String(UnicodeScalar(point1)) // "ಕ"
let s2 = String(UnicodeScalar(point2)) // "ಾ"

let combined = Character(s1 + s2) // "ಕಾ"
```

Another example (with code points outside of the "basic multilingual plane"):

```
let point1 = 0x1F1E9
let point2 = 0x1F1EA

let s1 = String(UnicodeScalar(point1)) // ""
let s2 = String(UnicodeScalar(point2)) // ""

let combined = Character(s1 + s2) // ""
```